# Bad quality of the sprite in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, sprites

I need to import a few sprites (background platform and sky) into my game scene but it seems that their quality after importing into Unity is too bad (they are blurred). The original resolution of this two images is big enough (2048 X 400 for background) and they are looking very nice in standard Windows image viewer. Here are the settings for these two textures:

**maxSize = 2048 
Format = truecolor 
TextureType = Sprite(2d)/nGUI 
FilterMode - point**

I am using Unity2D 4.5 Target resolution of my project is 1280*800.

Can anyone help me to solve these problem?
As you can see the grass on foreground looks very bloory (1 picture)
Texture settings (2 picture)
Original image (3 picture)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might help to include a screenshot as part of the question.

Comment: Okay, I added pictures.

Comment: Don't use Point filtering. Bilinear or Trilinear should look much better when scaled.

Comment: bummzack, I changed filter mode to trilinear, still no success((((

Comment: What format are they in? .png? .jpeg? Etc...

Comment: All of them are in png format (because I need them to have an opacity background)

Comment: You have the texture import settings with the Default profile displayed.  It is showing a Max Size value of 2048.  Is this overwritten with a smaller value by the specific platform settings for the current target platform?

Comment: Kelly Thomas, I am sorry, but I don't know((( How can I check this? My texture size is 2048*400. Max size is 2048. The target resolution is 1200*800.

Comment: You can check/change build platform [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PublishingBuilds.html), you can check platform specific settings for a texture by using the tabs just above Max Size on the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

If they get blurred be aware to import them in "Advanced" mode and disable "Mip Mapping" generation. 
Next check if any level of compression or filter is applied. Sometimes the filter tend to eat details of your image (try Point Filter or Bilinear Filter with small Anisotropic Level)
Also the best result is obtained when your textures are painted "pixel perfect" in your scene.
Try to import them as Truecolor without compression
As a last resource try to import them in "GUI/Editor Legacy Mode"

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to change these settings and i'll write later about my success

Answer (score 0):

Click on the resolution panel, in the Game section of the Editor, and then uncheck the "Low resolution" checkbox. I think they check that so the execution is faster when testing, but it blurs everything out and makes things look bad.